# Integration by parts to form an infinite series

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, taylor-expansion

The integral
$$I(\theta)=\int \sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}dt$$
can be evaluated with the quotient rule by writing $I(\theta)=\int \sin(\theta)d\theta $.

Instead, apply integration by parts more than once to obtain the series

\begin{align}
I(\theta)
&=\sin(\theta)\underbrace{\left[\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{\theta^7}{7!}+\dotsb\right]}_{\operatorname{MacLaurin}(\sin(\theta))}+\cos(\theta)\underbrace{\left[-\frac{\theta^2}{2}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\dotsb \right]}_{\operatorname{MacLaurin}(\cos(\theta)-1)} \tag{1}\\ 
&=1-\cos(\theta) +\text{constant} \\
&=-\cos(\theta)+\text{constant}
\end{align}
for $|\theta|\ll 1$.

However, the condition that $|\theta|\ll 1$ needs not to be true in general, is there a way to retrieve  $-\cos(\theta)+\text{constant}$ for $|\theta|\gg 1$ from $(1)$? Or is it impossible because something is going on at the 'endpoint' of the series?

Comment: There is no reason to tag every equation.  It is best practices only to tag those that you are actually going to refer to later.

Comment: Why do you think you need $|\theta|<1$? Surely the sine and cosine series converge everywhere?